# How to clean autowired object after each test execution

Tags: junit5

How to clean autowired object after each test execution. In my example TestClassSettings object does not get clean property and it uses the previous test class value. Here is the example:

TestClassSettings.java

```java
@Component
public class TestClassSettings{
    private String titleUnitCode = "99";
    private String fte = "1";
    private String testIndicator = "";

    public String getTitleUnitCode() {
        return titleUnitCode;
    }

    public void setTitleUnitCode(String titleUnitCode) {
        this.titleUnitCode = titleUnitCode;
    }

    public String getFte() {
        return fte;
    }

    public void setFte(String fte) {
        this.fte = fte;
    }

    public String getTestIndicator() {
        return testIndicator;
    }

    public void setTestIndicator(String testIndicator) {
        this.testIndicator = testIndicator;
    }
}
```

testClassSettings instance is not getting clean in between test cases.

TestLeaveHourCal_bweh6.java

```java
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(locations = { "classpath:service.xml"})
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class TestLeaveHourCal_bweh6 {
    @Autowired
    private ApproveTimesheetService approveTimesheetService;

    @Autowired
    private ComparePayUpdates comparePayUpdates;

    @Autowired
    public TestClassSettings testClassSettings; /* variable access type needs public */;

    @Autowired
    @RegisterExtension
    protected CreateTimesheetBeforeTestExecutionCallback beforeTestExecutionCallback; /* can not be private */

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        /* START SETTINGS */
        testClassSettings.setTestIndicator("6");
        testClassSettings.setTitleUnitCode("99");
        testClassSettings.setFte("0.5");
        /* END SETTINGS */
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @Tag("setBaselinePayUpdates")
    public void setBaselinePayUpdates() throws Exception {
    }
```

Comment: Fixed it by adding @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS) to fix the issue